# What does {'INTERFACE'} mean when returned from `invoke`, `modal` or `execute`?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

In version 2.72 a new return value for `invoke`, `modal` and `execute` got introduced: `{'INTERFACE'}`- It is documented as

> `INTERFACE` Interface, Handled but not executed (popup menus).

What does this actually mean when comparing the Operator's control flow to that of returning one of the other values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The 'INTERFACE' operator return value is used to indicate where an operator has successfully completed by opening a menu or other UI component.**

The comment in the source code for the operator return types states that it is:

```
/* "used for operators that act indirectly (eg. popup menu)" */
/* "note: this isn't great design (using operators to trigger UI) avoid where possible." */
```

> Source: source/blender/makesdna/DNA_windowmanager_types.h

This new return type was added during Commit - [Fix T41041](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/commit/2f0bdcb306999ff610ecc6073af27b2311924153): "*'Delete keyframe' removes markers too*"

Reason for commit update was:

> "Operators that trigger UI events (but nothing else)
>   were using 'CANCELLED' making it impossible to tell if an invoke
>   function failed, or opened a menu."

Comment: I wonder why Operators that trigger UI events don't simply return 'FINISHED' :?

Comment: I think the devs wanted to distinguish between code where an operator runs code and completes, and when the operator triggers a UI component opening that then runs further operators which could fail or succeed.